# Laptops fans running very loudly with Xubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, xubuntu, fan

I've installed Xubuntu after having Linux Mint (which, to note, also had the fans running loudly, maybe a bit less, but they were very loud still) and the fans are simply running all the time. I'm not sure what I should do to fix this. Here's my inxi -Fxz:

```
System:
  Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 
  Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Inspiron 17-7779 v: N/A 
  serial: <filter> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 009VVM v: A00 serial: <filter> UEFI: Dell v: 1.27.0 
  date: 01/18/2019 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 1.5 Wh condition: 1.5/56.0 Wh (3%) 
  model: Samsung SDI DELL J9NH26A status: Unknown 
  Device-1: hidpp_battery_1 model: Logitech Wireless Mouse M185 
  charge: 55% (should be ignored) status: Discharging 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-7500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  arch: Amber Lake rev: 9 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx 
  bogomips: 23199 
  Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 400/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 
  3: 800 4: 800 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel 
  bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX] vendor: Dell driver: nvidia 
  v: 440.100 bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia 
  unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce 940MX/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.100 
  direct render: Yes 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Dell 
  driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-42-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wireless 3165 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: e000 
  bus ID: 02:00.0 
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 2.73 TiB used: 1.64 TiB (60.2%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM035-1RK172 size: 931.51 GiB 
  ID-2: /dev/sdb type: USB vendor: Western Digital model: WD easystore 25FA 
  size: 1.82 TiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.40 GiB used: 8.29 GiB (0.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 61.0 C mobo: 51.0 C sodimm: 38.0 C gpu: nvidia 
  temp: 55 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 4720 
Info:
  Processes: 218 Uptime: 1h 25m Memory: 15.51 GiB used: 2.77 GiB (17.9%) 
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: N/A Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 
  inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Fan controls are often firmware based. You should look into BIOS settings.  If the fan doesn't spin at the same speed all the time then the fan speed is probably based on CPU temp.  Other than monitoring system resources to make sure nothing has run amok, there's not much you can do.  It's better than heat damage to your laptop (or your lap)

Comment: Which version of xubuntu?  I've seen several posts related to Ubuntu 20 and nvidia driver issues that caused this.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa). Indeed I have NVIDIA Drivers:
CPU:
 Dual Core Intel Core i7-7500U 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce 940MX/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.100

So far, I've installed 'auto-cpufreq' from 'Software' and it  seems to have slightly fixed it. The fans are no longer running all the time, but sometimes will start running out of the blue.